# Javascript - How would I send a http request without it being redirected?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to send a http request to another site on a different domain. If you don't think that this is possible, send a redirected link to [this](https://www.hurl.it/) site, and it will come up with the "Location" header. All I want is the location header, since this website redirects me to a different key every time you visit it.

How would I do exactly what [this](https://www.hurl.it/) site is doing, but only for the "Location" header? All I want is to access the location for which the site is sending me to.

```
var request = new Request('https://example.com/redirectThatDownloadsThenCloses', {
method: 'GET', 
mode: 'no-cors', 
redirect: 'manual',
headers: new Headers()
});
fetch(request).then(response => {        
const headers = response.headers.entries();
   let header = headers.next();
     console.log(header.value);
});
```

Comment: Please include some codes that you've tried so far.

Comment: I added some. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp , i suggest you visit this page

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can do an XmlHttpRequest to a different domain only if the domain you are calling respond with an Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
To retrieve only header you need a call with verb HEAD.
If the other domain doesn't allow cross domain request I suggest to do the request server side where there are no limitation.
If you only need to call the url without read the response you can load the url into an hidden iframe.

```
<iframe id="myIframe" src="#" style`="display:none"></`iframe>

document.getElementById("myIframe").src=myUrl;
```

Comment: I don't know JavaScript very well. How would I load it into a hidden Iframe?
Like I said, this is completely possible with the site I am using, as I did it via hurt.it, and it showed the location. The page opens and (Almost instantly) downloads and closes. I want to capture the "Location" header of the page before it redirects.

Comment: I have to do the request client sided, the key that the website is sending will not be accepted in server side.